# Como converter essa data para datetime no oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Maneira correta de converter a data `'27/12/2016 16:31:39,137000000'` para datetime(timestamp(6)) no oracle?

Algumas tentativas frustadas que resultam no erro `ORA-01821: formato de data não reconhecido
01821. 00000 -  "date format not recognized"`:

```
  SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('27/12/2016 16:31:39,137000000', 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'), 'DD/MM/YYYY') DT_C FROM DUAL;
  SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('27/12/2016 16:31:39,137000000', 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS.FF9'), 'DD/MM/YYYY') DT_C FROM DUAL;
  SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('27/12/2016 16:31:39,137000000', 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS.FF'), 'DD/MM/YYYY') DT_C FROM DUAL;
```

Isso funciona, mas a data com a virgula e os números depois dos segundos não:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('27/12/2016 16:31:39', 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'), 'DD/MM/YYYY') DT_C FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se entendi, veja se era isso que você queria:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('27/12/2016 16:31:39', 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') DT_C FROM DUAL;
```

Para mostrar os milissegundos:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP ('10-Sep-02 14:10:10.123000', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS.FF')
```

FROM DUAL;

Com timestamp:

```
select to_char(systimestamp,'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss.FF') as ts from dual;
```

Comment: a data é 27/12/2016 16:31:39,137000000

Comment: tipo, é literalmente isso q eu recebo como data

Comment: use esse codigo entao, é so editar o timestamp pelo que vc quer:
select 
   to_char(systimestamp,'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss.FF') as ts
from dual;

OU esse:

SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP ('10-Sep-02 14:10:10.123000', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS.FF')
   FROM DUAL;